# Как найти площадь пересечения прямоугольников?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть 2 прямоугольника, как найти площадь их пересечения? Стороны прямоугольников паралельны осям. 
Как реализовать данный алгоритм на C#?

Comment: тебе бы на форум математиков надо =)

Comment: [форум математиков](http://math.hashcode.ru/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если задача - [пересечение прямоугольников](http://olympic.tusur.ru/problems/vol1/141.htm), то решение сводится к использованию метода [Rectangle.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y10fyck0.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо ! Не знал об этом методе.